# Show which group the element with Z=31 belongs

Tags: periodic-table

[image]
and I understand it belongs to the 13 th group, but my teacher wants to express it as IIIA, so how should I convert it in my mind?

Answer (score 4):

This is the old periodic table in which are still used these groups. You should avoid its use, but if your teacher needs you to learn them anyway, here they are:

[image]

Comment: See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_%28periodic_table%29) for more information. The [key publication for renumbering](http://dx.doi.org/10.1351%2Fpac198860030431) should be free access. Also see rule IR-3.5 in the [IUPAC red book](http://media.iupac.org/publications/books/rbook/Red_Book_2005.pdf).